# CUPS Printer In Use

Tags: debian, cups

I recently added some printers to Debian Linux 9.  Whenever I try to print to any one of them, CUPS reports "The printer is in use".  This happens from both the lp command and the CUPS web interface.  Here's the config for one of my printers:

```
<Printer IT>
UUID urn:uuid:04d3f4a4-aa59-3760-6bcc-8c7383edae70
Info IT
Location Office
MakeModel Lexmark X658de
DeviceURI lpd://192.168.1.60/IT
State Idle
StateTime 1553021794
ConfigTime 1553021782
Type 8425692
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
</Printer>
```

I can telnet into the printer.
My cupsd.conf file looks like this:

```
LogLevel warn
PageLogFormat
MaxLogSize 0
# Allow remote access
Port 631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock
Listen localhost:631
Listen 192.168.6.200:631
# Share local printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
DefaultAuthType Basic
WebInterface Yes
<Location />
  # Allow shared printing and remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin>
  # Allow remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  # Allow remote access to the configuration files...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin/log>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
  # Allow remote access to the log files...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Policy default>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-   Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifi$
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Pri$
    AuthType Default
   AuthType Default
      Require user @SYSTEM
      Order deny,allow
    </Limit>
    <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
      Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
      Order deny,allow
    </Limit>
    <Limit All>
      Order deny,allow
    </Limit>
  </Policy>
  <Policy authenticated>
    JobPrivateAccess default
    JobPrivateValues default
    SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
    SubscriptionPrivateValues default
    <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
      AuthType Default
      Order deny,allow
    </Limit>
    <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifi$
      AuthType Default
      Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
      Order deny,allow
    </Limit>
    <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
      AuthType Default
      Require user @SYSTEM
      Order deny,allow
   </Limit>
    <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Pri$
      AuthType Default
      Require user @SYSTEM
      Order deny,allow
    </Limit>
    <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
      AuthType Default
      Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
      Order deny,allow
    </Limit>
    <Limit All>
      Order deny,allow
    </Limit>
  </Policy>
```

I have these printers set up on another Debian box and they work fine.  I'm at a loss in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this answer does not address the OP's question, but I ran into this question with the same error.  So hoping this might help someone down the road ...

My issue was that **one of my printer's cartridges was empty**.  Replacing the empty cartridge stopped the "The printer is in use" error, and the doc printed straight away.